# Android rtmp Vitamio Exception

Tags: android, vitamio

Downloaded Vitamio rtmp player app and lib, changed gradle dependency to `22.0.1` so it runs but  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.vov.vitamio.R$raw" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.butterflytv.vitamio_with_librtmp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.butterflytv.vitamio_with_librtmp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]` occurs and I don't have any idea what type of exception is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Java Build Path from the menu on the left select the Order and Export tab
From the list make sure the libraries or external jars you added to your project are checked.